# Gtk#/Gdk# Convert Gtk.Image (From IconName) to Gdk.Pixmap

Tags: c#, gtk#

I am trying to load a Gdk.Pixmap from an IconName loaded through a Gtk.Image. However, I cannot figure out how to actually convert this.

If I run this code:

`Gtk.Image.NewFromIconName("computer", IconSize.Dialog)`

How can I convert this to a Gdk.Pixmap? The Gtk.Image.Pixmap property cannot be used because it expects the Gtk.Image wraps a Gdk.Pixmap.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of digging I found the best option. Instead of using `Image.NewFromIconName` it is easier to use

```
IconSet iconset = new IconSet();
IconSource source = new IconSource();
source.IconName = "icon-name";
iconset.AddSource(source);
Pixbuff p = iconset.RenderIcon(new Style(), TextDirection.None, StateType.Normal, IconSize.SmallToolbar, controlOrNull, "")
```